# How can I hook into Spring's @RequestBody argument resolving to resolve my own argument using the body of the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dry

In the process of developing our app, we found ourselves doing something like this in our controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SimpleMasterWidget doStuff(@RequestBody ClientData clientData, ServerData serverData) throws Exception
{
        pushClientDataToServerData(clientData, serverData);
        //stuff specific to this operation on the serverData
        return whatever;
}
```

The `pushClientDataToServerData(clientData, serverData);` call gets duplicated in every POST request. Now, I understand that there really shouldn't be any need to push clientData to serverData, but there is legacy code that forces us to do this.

Currently we are implementing the [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) interface to resolve the `ServerData` argument. To remove all the duplicated `pushClientDataToServerData` calls I want to be able to resolve the `ServerData` argument with the `ClientData` already pushed into it.

Now in the argument resolver, I have access to the `NativeWebRequest` so I could probably get the request body through there and deserialize it and all that. However, I don't want to have to reimplement what Spring is already doing with the `@RequestBody` annotation.

So my question boils down to this: Is there a way I can call into Spring's stuff in the argument resolver so that I can get the deserialized `ClientData` object and call `pushClientDataToServerData` right within the argument resolver? Then all the controller methods would just look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SimpleMasterWidget doStuff(ServerData serverData) throws Exception
{
        //stuff specific to this operation on the serverData
        return whatever;
}
```

And the `pushClientDataToServerData` call would be in only one place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a good candidate for Spring AOP

Comment: I'm only familiar with Spring AOP on a very high level. How exactly would I use it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good candidate for Spring AOP. Below is just an example of pointcut, you should improve it to catch all possible methods:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class PushClientDataAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(* com.xyz.myapp.dao.*.*(..) && args(clientData, serverData) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody))")
    public void pushClientData(ClientData clientData, ServerData serverData) {
        pushClientDataToServerData(clientData, serverData);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Either answer the OP or not